# Class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ always even?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $n$ be a negative square-free even integer. Does it necessarily follow that the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ is even?

Comment: No. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group

Comment: @JackYoon You mean $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Gauss proved that the class number $h(d)$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$, for squarefree $d<0$ is divisible by $2^{s-1}$ for $d\equiv 1,2 \bmod 4$, and divisible by $2^s$ for $d\equiv 3\bmod 4$, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=f2njBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA622&lpg=PA622&dq=class+number+of+imaginary+quadratic+field+is+divisible+by+2+for+even+n&source=bl&ots=UASXgsannw&sig=Fbc24u6cWvriLnU0IJ2JNVAF4tg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidnbTWv9nLAhVF2xoKHT3lAXk4ChDoAQgaMAA#v=onepage&q=class%20number%20of%20imaginary%20quadratic%20field%20is%20divisible%20by%202%20for%20even%20n&f=false). Here $s$ denotes the number of prime factors of $d$. If $d\neq -2$ is even, $s\ge 2$ and we are done. So the answer is: except for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$, which has class number $1$, all other 
imaginary quadratic number fields  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-n})$, for even $n \neq -2$ have even class numer.